# Why is my desktop the same as home folder?

Tags: directory, xdg

My desktop (not the `/home/user/Desktop` folder) shows the contents of my `/home/user` folder. I don't know how I have done it and **can I have some help on undoing it?** The `/home/user/Desktop` folder just contains my desktop files which do not appear on my desktop.

Comment: Is your `~/Desktop` folder located on another partition?

Comment: `~/Desktop` is on the same partition.

Comment: Also visit :http://askubuntu.com/q/66322/256099

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can change you desktop folder i.e the folder you want to use   as your Desktop.

- Open the `~/.config` folder. (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to show hidden folders.)

  [image]
- Open the `user-dirs.dirs` file  in gedit.

[image]

- Change `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` to the folder you want to show as your Desktop folder. In your case it is `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=$HOME/Desktop`

  [image]
- Now restart nautilus using `nautilus -q` or `killall nautilus` and again opening it from Dash.

Comment: This answer is still up to date on Trusty 14.04.4. Thanks. +1

Comment: still works in 16.04

Comment: still works in 18.10

Comment: still works in debian testing, but the nautilus stuff is a bit different is xfce4 of course.

Answer (score 18):

As simply or shortly, You can set default folders with help of **`xdg-user-dirs-update`** command.

Run following command in your case:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set DESKTOP "$HOME/Desktop"
```

Then logout and login back to show/change effect.

---

From `man xdg-user-dirs-update`:

```
NAME
       xdg-user-dirs-update - Update XDG user dir configuration

SYNOPSIS
       xdg-user-dirs-update [OPTION...] [--set NAME PATH...]

DESCRIPTION
       xdg-user-dirs-update updates the current state of the users user-dirs.dir. If none existed before then one is created
       based on the system default values, or falling back to the old non-translated filenames if such directories exists. The
       list of old directories used are: ~/Desktop, ~/Templates and ~/Public.
```