# I logged on saw copy of path directorys, files etc all over my laptop screen

Tags: files, icons

I just logged onto my laptop. The `music`, `videos`, `pictures`, `public`, `downloads` and `files` from my `home` all over my laptop background. The original files are still working. I did a trial with my videos and deleted on my laptop and said the directory couldn't be found. Then I restored it from the bin. It was working again. So I've realised ended making copies of them. How do you remove them?
My laptop background looks really cluttered.
I've checked: `gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` again:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Do you have a Desktop directory on the background in addition to the other files from your home directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my desktop the same as home folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523167/why-is-my-desktop-the-same-as-home-folder)

Comment: I was on that to move a missing desktop file earlier. I came back and checked. Nothing had changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shut my laptop when I was finished with it. I turned it on again and everything was "back to normal".

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your issue:

- Select all files in your desktop background,
- Cut them,
- Open a file browser and go to home,
- Paste them

Comment: I tried. 'I got the you cannot move a file over itself'. The source is already there.