I accidentaly deleted all of the folders in my /home/user directory
I once had:
Desktop
Downloads
Ect. ect.
But their names were in a different language, and trying to fix them... I deleted those.
Can someone help me restore the folders? I arledy emptied the trash.

This question is similar to: How to recover deleted files?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

And after you have restored your data... to change the names of the folders check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/66322/how-can-i-change-the-desktop-folder-path

This question is similar to: How can I change the Desktop folder path?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Are you just trying to restore those (empty) folders or were  there files in there that you need to try to recover?

unfortunately, you cant recover your files after deleting them via the terminal, because them dont go to a trash. so it is always recommended to create a backup. But if you have something important to recover, With hard work you can try to use forensic techniques to try to recover something, but this is very complex and difficult.
